# Rydberg quasimolecules & stark states?

Tags: wavefunction, atomic-physics, visualization

I found this image :[image] on the internet and I traced it back to [this article](http://iopscience.iop.org/0953-4075/labtalk-article/47053) ,I wanted to use it as part of an architectural visualization for my project(architecture) but for this to happen I need to understand what is it about ,I understand what a "probability density" is ,and some "good enough" concepts of quantum mechanics "Without the hard math", but I couldn't find anything about stark states , all I could find on Wikipedia and the internet "Google" was stark effect but nothing that points out what this visualization "image" is about ?

Comment: There are lots of links if you put " around the words. eg. http://iopscience.iop.org/1367-2630/13/6/063036